# How to style a sibling component in Angular2?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a search component containing a logo, a searchbar and a routeroutlet. The execution of a search navigates to the resultlist, which is the pseudo html outlined here:

```html
<search>
  <logo></logo>
  <searchbar></searchbar>
  <result-list></result-list>
</search>
```

I like to style logo and searchbar differently on the results page so I tried to select the logo with `:host >>> logo` and the `/deep/` alternative from the `result-list`component. That doesn't work. Is there a way to select siblings?

Here a small plnkr to demonstrate the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0CLjcsftbqe0kHKrKks?p=preview Here I would like to style from `resultlist` the `logo` and the `searchbar`to be black.

Comment: dep of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file

Comment: I read that post, that is from the parent and not from a sibling.

Comment: would you mind creating a plunk?

Comment: I got your point but I don't think there is any way to style a sibling component from sibling. either you can do it from parent or child.

Comment: Ok. I guess then I'll need to give the logo and searchbar component a parameter to add a style class for the result-page. Kind of contradicts the component approach.

Comment: again I don't understand but sounds like a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting is basically sharing global application state `isSearchResultList: boolean` across multiple components.

The obvious naive solution would be to hold the state at the respective shared parent component, and set it based on the current router-outlet.

```
<search>
  <logo [isSearchResultList]="isSearchResultList"></logo>
  <searchbar [isSearchResultList]="isSearchResultList"></searchbar>
  <result-list></result-list>
</search>
```

Comment: I hoped to not put a state in there. Similar solution below.

Comment: I can relate to that, I'd be interested in alternative approaches as well.

Answer (score 2):

A Similar solution to the one from [Jens Habegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1792564/jens-habegger) using `:host-context(myCssClass)` and a conditional. The style needs to be added to the `logo` and the `searchbar` component.

```html
<search>
  <logo [class.myCssClass]="isSearchResultList"></logo>
  <searchbar [class.myCssClass]="isSearchResultList"></searchbar>
  <result-list></result-list>
</search>
```

```css
:host-context(.myCssClass) {
  color: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use services for communication between components and ngClass for dynamic styling.

notification.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  private static _emitters: { [ID: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {};

  static get(ID: string): EventEmitter<any> {
    if (!this._emitters[ID]) {
      this._emitters[ID] = new EventEmitter();
    }
    return this._emitters[ID];
  }
}
```

When sibling component run send a message.

bar.component.ts

```
import { NotificationService } from 'notification.service';
....
ngOnInit() {
      NotificationService.get('barcomponent').emit(true);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
      NotificationService.get('barcomponent').emit(false);
  }
...
```

Listen to incoming messages from your component.

foo.component.ts

```
import { NotificationService } from 'notification.service';
....
ngOnInit() {
    NotificationService.get('barcomponent').subscribe(value => {
        this.activateStyle = value;
    });
  }
....
```

You can apply any class via ngClass

foo.component.html

```
....
<div [ngClass]="{'my-css-class':activateStyle}">
  ...
</div>
....
```