# angular2 child comment how to extends parent styles

Tags: angular, styles

I have two components, I want inner component extends outside component styles

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    style: [ '.panel{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc}' ],
    template: 'parent'
})

class ParentComponent 
{
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div class=".panel"></div>'
})

class ChildComponent 
{
}
```

using like this I want show a square

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html) on for your child component. You could maybe set the view encapsulation to none for the child component so it will inherit the parent styles:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from "@angular/core"
@Component({
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div class=".panel"></div>'
})
```

I have never really tested it for this use-case but you might be able to do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

You have the power to give child's css from parent component using `>>>` selector as shown below,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    style: [ `
           :host >>> child .myCssclass
             {
               width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc
             } 
           `],
    template: 'parent'
})

class ParentComponent 
{
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div class="myCssclass"></div>'
})

class ChildComponent 
{
}
```

[How to style child components from parent component's css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Comment: if my using styleUrls ?

Comment: styleUrls: [':host >>> child ./parent.css'] ?

Comment: No. `stylesUrls` requires external css file. in that file you have to define it and pass that relative path to `styelsUrls`

Comment: Thanks @echonax !!

Comment: @micronyks Oh lol, since I also upvoted I thought you can see who upvoted you xD

Answer (score 0):

The template of the child component should be like this:

```
template: '<div class="panel"></div>'
```

The class name should be without the dot ;)

Anyway this is not the Angular question. It belongs to CSS.

Next - the template of the parent should be:

```
template: '<child></child>'
```

And in the final template code you may leave just the

```
<parent></parent>
```