# Overriding components styles in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I need to override the styles of components from outside in angular5. I've tried the below code and it's not working.

In this project, the viewEncapsulation is default ie Emulated.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-vivek-button class="testClass">Primary</app-vivek-button>
```

**app.component.css**

```
::ng-deep app-vivek-button.testClass {
    background-color: tomato !important;
    color: teal;
}
```

**vivek-button.component.html**

```
<button class="button-style">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

**vivek-button.component.css**

```
:host{
    display: block;
}

.button-style {
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(60, 114, 230);
    color:#fff;
    height: 32px;
    border: none;
}
```

Tried to follow all the ways mentioned in this [question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting required vad in `style.css` which is global to application.

```
    app-vivek-button.testClass {
    background-color: tomato !important;
    color: teal;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, it should change. But I'm getting the same result.