# How to apply styles to component-B from component-A stylesheet in Angular-Cli without making styles apply globally?

Tags: css, angular

I have two Angular components:

```
@Component({
    selector: ‘component-a’,
    templateUrl: './component-a.html',
    styleUrls: [ ‘./component-a.scss' ],
})

@Component({
    selector: ‘component-b’,
    templateUrl: './component-b.html',
    styleUrls: [ ‘./component-b.scss' ],
})
```

In `component-a` HTML:

```
<div class=“cmp-a-container”>
    component A
    <component-b></component-b>
</div>
```

and in `component-b` HTML:

```
<div class=“cmp-b-container”>
    component B
</div>
```

`component-b` is reused inside other components. But when `component-b` is used inside `component-a` I want it to have a set of specific styles applied on the `.cmp-b-container` class.

If I add the following code into `component-a.scss`,

```
.cmp-a-container {
  .cmp-b-container { /* Styles here */ }
}
```

The styles won’t apply. I believe this is how Angular works.

So my solution to this is, adding the styles on the styles.scss (the global sass file).

Is this the right way to do this or is there a way to apply styles specified in `component-a`’s stylesheet to `component-b`’s inner html when it’s wrapped by `component-a`?. Why has Angular not made this possible?

I'm using Angular-Cli and Sass.

Comment: duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use ::ng-deep so that your styles propagates to child components, see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

It should go something like this:

```
.cmp-a-container ::ng-deep{
  .cmp-b-container { /* Styles here */ }
}
```