# How to inherit css styles in child component from parent in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular5

I have a parent component inside which I have a child component. The parent component have some css classes, where child component extends them. I tried to use :host as looking at documentation, but cant't seem to get it work properly.

child component:

```
<div class="table-row body">
<div class="table-cell body-content-outer-wrapper">
    <div class="body-content-inner-wrapper">
        <div class="body-content">
            <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
            <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
            <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

parent component:

```
         <div class="table container">
                 <div class="table-row header">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
                        <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                  </div>
            <app-child-component></app-child-component>
                </div>
```

parent component css:

```
  :host  .table {
    display: table;
  }

  :host .table-row {
    display: table-row;
  }

  :host .table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  :host .container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100vh;
  }

  :host  .header {
    background: cyan;
 }

   :host .body {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
 }

  :host .body-content-outer-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
 }

 .body-content-inner-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}

 .body-content {
    position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

The problem if even I put css classes inside the child component, the layout breaks just because there is a child-component template. So the main question is what is proper way for child to inherit extend css from parent component?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Why make things complex?

Ideal way to do would be to add refrence of parent css file in child component as well.

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'child-app',
    templateUrl: `./child.component.html`,
    styleUrls:['./parent/parent.component.css', './child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent { }
```

Comment: my mistake, thanks anyway, just found that there is no parent child architecture, but 2 siblings components. What would be the best way in this scenario? Should I move classes to global css?

Comment: If both siblings have any parent, you can do as suggested in my answer else You can have a shared css file and add reference of shared css under "StyleUrls" in both component.

Comment: if I do this, then each component is different scope, and styles are not inherited.

Comment: Are you working in AngularJS, For Angular2+. there is no limit of scope you can have shared components, shared css among multiple component just by adding reference to StyleUrls.

Comment: Angular 2+, the problem is that css breaks, because of something like <app-child> >> <div class "table-row body">. The class table row is there but it breaks the app. Only when I move class to the actual <app-child> selector it works. But I don't need it like that.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to add classes to <child> tag inside parent? If yes you should directly apply case in child component itself.

Comment: Very much discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file, looks like there is a way with ::ng-deep but that will soon be deprecated, so there is no option that exists. Your solution will fail when there are mulitple parents that want to override css of same child.

Comment: If you read answer again, it is about a child using css of parent not the other way round, and it should work with multiple parents as well.

Comment: That breaks the Open-Close principle. We should not modify the child component for every parent.

Comment: @mdarefull How does it even closely apply to open-close principle? We are not adding new feature here to child.

Comment: @mdareful Aren't we? Assume the child will be used by another parent, then we should go to the child component and modify it, to reference the new style sheet, possibly breaking its previous usage.

Comment: If we start changing child components as per different parents' needs, doesn't it violate SRP ! I won't create such component which needs to be changed in order to be used. Again, if we are talking about making reusable components/angular elements, in that case there shouldn't be any inheritance from parent at all.

Comment: This is very good, but I have a conditional on my class. Specifically with `[ngClass]` I hope that using component input it inherited too!

Comment: This works, but the only problem with it is that you end up creating duplicate copies of the stylesheet for each component. If this pattern is used extensively, it will bloat the size of the stylesheet considerably.

Comment: Why create duplicate copies, you can use same copy everywhere.

Comment: You’ll also have a problem if you use Sass: it won’t compile your variables if you add the style sheet in your component. You’ll have to add (at)import '../parent/parent.component.scss' in your child style sheet. It also works for 2 siblings: you can create a global style sheet next to styles.scss and (at)import it in the siblings style sheets (with a '../../other-style.scss' path).

Answer (score 9):

With `::ng-deep`, styles will be applied to the current component, but also trickle down to the components that are children to the current component in the component tree.

Example:

```
:host ::ng-deep app-child-component {
       color:yellow;
     }
```

A good resource - [Styles Between Components in Angular 2+](https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/)

Comment: `ng-deep` is deprecated: angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: What is the new way of doing this ? Or is it not supported anymore ?

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative to ::ng-deep and referencing the parent's css file, is to use the **encapsulation** component propertie :

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

the parent css with flow to all it's childs.

Comment: but it will also flow to the rest of the application. Much like putting login.component.css in the global styles. 
Also, it makes these components susceptible to break other components.

Comment: @SoEzPz that's not true, I just tested and I can clearly apply a class declares in the scss of a child component in any parent. ViewEncapsulation.None makes these styles global.

Answer (score 1):

why you're trying to make it complex, you can just import your parent component CSS into your cild component CSS