# Angular 6 - ng-bootstrap - Style Tabs

Tags: angular, angular-components, ng-bootstrap

I'm having this bootstrap tabs

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 1">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 1
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 2">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 2
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

The text color on the tabs is blue. I know that if I create global styles I can override the defaults. But I want to style the tabs from the parent component

I know that I can style children components but it doesn't work in this case ([How to style child components from parent component's css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)). Any advice?

```
styles: [
`
 :host { color: red; }

 :host ::ng-deep parent {
   color:blue;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child{
   color:orange;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child.class1 {
   color:yellow;
 }
 :host ::ng-deep child.class2{
   color:pink;
 }
`
],
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the following template which uses ng-bootstrap tabs:

```
<ngb-tabset class="tabset1">
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 1">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 1
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 2">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 2
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

you can override the default tab title style with these CSS rules:

```
:host ::ng-deep .tabset1 a.nav-link {
  color: green;
}

:host ::ng-deep .tabset1 a.nav-link.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpmdsy) for a demo.

Note: If the attribute `class="tabset1"` is not set on the `ngb-tabset` element, the selector `.tabset1` should be removed from the CSS styles.