# Angular passing css to child component - best practice

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I wonder what is a good practice of styling elements inside of child components from parent component level. I generally do it in 2 different aproaches:

## 1.Using /deep/ [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/QnJwiTgPBrlZmAgA?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Benefits:

1. Less code
2. We use only css to style elements

Disadvantages:

1. We cannot use properties from typescript like in a 2nd approach
2. We break component hermetization

## 2.Using input in child component [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/24kjP7x49BsnxNhL?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

Benefits:

1. We can use properties from typescript
2. We don't break component hermetization

Disadvantages:

1. More code and complicated - the deeper child, the more passes
2. We sometimes don't need logic - but we are forced to write in .ts instead of using pure css mechanism

As you can see I have found pros and cons for both ways. I feel like answer might be "It depends" or maybe I miss another approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style child components from parent component's CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)