# How to make a style or stylesheet available to children components

Tags: angular

How can I make this style available to child components?

```
.invalid {
  border-color: #dd2c00;
}
```

Is it possible to make an entire component's style sheet available to child components?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style child components from parent component's CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Comment: answers in there are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your class, add ::ng-deep in front of it and you'll be fine.

```
::ng-deep .invalid {
  border-color: #dd2c00;
}
```

As for your other question:

> Is it possible to make an entire component's style sheet available to child components?

You can change the component's [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) property to `Native` or `None`

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
  ...
})
```