# Right way to override child component style from host component angular

Tags: angular, angular2viewencapsulation

What is the right way to override child component style from host component. I tried using  `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` but i need to write the override stuff in style.sass file rather than host component. What should be the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-w6ezr9?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: Some good info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have control on the child component code, you can define a `customStyle` input property:

```
@Input() customStyle: {};
```

```
<div class="child-div" [ngStyle]="customStyle">I am the child</div>
```

and pass it from the parent component:

```
<app-child [customStyle]="style1"></app-child>
```

```
style1 = {
  backgroundColor: "red",
  height: "150px"
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-3ebbvk) for a demo.

---

A similar technique can allow to pass a specific style attribute to the child component:

```
@Input() backgroundColor: string;
```

```
<div class="child-div" [style.background-color]="backgroundColor">I am the child</div>
```

from the parent component:

```
<app-child backgroundColor="red"></app-child>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-lqhe6e?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts) for a demo.

---

Otherwise, until an alternative method is proposed by Angular, you can use the `::ng-deep` [shadow-piercing descendant combinator](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to modify the child component styling from the parent CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep .parent .child-div {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 200px;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-aqjqgt?file=app%2Fapp.component.css) for a demo.

Comment: But we are not supposed to use ::ng-deep right as it will be deprecated.

Comment: You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47024236/1009922) about the deprecation of `::ng-deep`. I agree with the accepted answer: use it until Angular suggests an alternative technique.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can do it with `::ng-deep` or `ViewEncapsulation.None` (at the present time).

Comment: Can you show me right way to do it with viewEncapsulation.None. Is its case need to write override styles in styles.scss right?

Comment: If you turn off the view encapsulation in both components, you can alter the child component styling from the parent CSS (or from `styles.css`). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-zbk3ah).

Comment: Cool. ::ng-deep looks good for me when compared to encapsulation. As it keeps intact the encapsulations of the respective component and when required only will be updated from parent.

Comment: I agree. We will see what Angular suggests when `:ng-deep` is officially removed.

Comment: You can use encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None in "parent" and add !important to the .css, e.g.  background-color: lime!important

Comment: `::ng-deep` is deprecated but unfortunately the only option I know, you can check this discussion for more information about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308475/9325419

Answer (score 2):

My "way" is using viewEncapsulation.None, important and add class to the child.
the [forked stackblitz's Connors](https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewencapsulation-turned-off-4ajixz?file=app/app.component.html)

```
//The parent
.child1 .child-div {
  background-color: lime!important;
  height: 200px!important;
}

<div style="text-align: center;" class='parent'>Hi I am the app-root and I contain child-comp!
<app-child class="child1"></app-child>
<app-child ></app-child>
</div>
```