# Is there a way to replace my component in dom with its contents?

Tags: angular, typescript, jqxwidgets

I am currently using a 3rd party utility, called JQXDocking.  Its a pretty simple and straight-forward design.  Upon looking into it on a deeper level though I figured the page would get bulky so, i abstracted all of the docked widgets to custom components.

The issue with the jqxDocking concept though is that it is looking for divs, etc.  I break the design because instead of a direct child being a div, it is my custom component

```
// What it was
<jqxDocking>
<div><div>title</div><div>content</div></div>
</jqxDocking>

// What it is now.
<jqxDocking>
  <my-component></my-component>
</jqxDocking>

inside my-component has the proper dom structure that jqxDocking is looking for.  So i was hoping for a way to replace in markup correctly such that the component works.
```

because of this new layer in the DOM, the parent component cant interpret my code correctly.

Is there a way to create a custom component but replace with the template html?

So, if i wrap it with a div, it will gain part of its implementation

```
<jqxDocking>
  <div class=column">
    <div class="card">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</jqxDocking>
```

but its title is undefined, because it doesnt understand the title which is in my component.

So i pull that from the component

```
<jqxDocking>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="card">
      <div>Title</div>
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</jqxDocking>
```

So I could do that, but it just doesnt look all that good.  I may have to just template that out in the markup, instead of componentizing.

Comment: what happens if you wrap `<my-component></my-component>` inside a `div`?

Comment: I tried that originally.  It makes it drag-droppable like the widget but it has no understanding the card title, which is defined in my component.  So if i keep abstracting it eventually becomes `<div><div>title</div><my-component></my-component></div>` but as you can see, since everything has a title, and everything is encapsulated with a div, i figured all of it could be abstractable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having the `my-component` element in the output HTML, you can define the component selector as an attribute selector:

```
selector: "[my-component]"
```

and set that attribute on the container element in the template:

```
<jqxDocking my-component></jqxDocking>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcbjxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-component.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: How would `Input()` properties be handled? Would they just be applied like normal to jqxDocking, or in your sample the div?

Comment: You can bind them in the container component element, as shown in [the updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcbjxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: EUREKA.  I am going to test and flush this out some more, but i think this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This does solve the base question.  The only thing I can see which is producing a hiccup is that styles are not bleeding into the component.  Its a good thing, but the parent styles are doing things like "jqx-window-content-dark" and then all child div under it are stylized.  Since Technically the content is still its own component, the CSS will not resolve.  But that seems to be a different question

Comment: If you have control on the jqx CSS, you can add `::ng-deep` in front of the style rules, to affect the child component elements (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54329016/1009922)).