# In Angular 7 - How do I style HTML thats projected using ng-content

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli, angular7

In Angular 7 - How do I style HTML thats projected using ng-content.

**Tech**: Angular 7, Angular CLI, SASS, HTML5, Webpack.

**My Code:**

**Note**: my component html with transclusion / projection.
This component has a scss file and the html that comes through the ng-content can only be styled if ng-deep is used e.g. :host::ng-deep

```
<table>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</table>
```

**This is my sass for the above components html:**

```
:host::ng-deep {
  table {
    background-color: map-get($theme-brand, flat);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid map-get($theme-contrast, contrast-8);
    border-radius: 5px;

    tr {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    th, td {
      @extend %p-2;
      word-break: break-all;
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      text-align: right;
      width: 250px;
      color: map-get($theme-typography-color, regular);

      &:first-child {
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: So the above css for tr and th, td won't get styled due to the projection preventing the styling unless I use the ng-deep.

**Things tried**:

- ng-deep (which works but don't want to use as its deprecated soon by browsers).

Comment: the deprecated thing is true but idk when is taking place. I have heard of that since angular 4 lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to override child component style from host component angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328837/right-way-to-override-child-component-style-from-host-component-angular)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling/54913259#54913259), you have two different approaches:

1: Use the [::slotted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted) pseudo selector, which is starting to be supported by new browsers. To use that, you will need to change the `encapsulation` property of `@Component` to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`.

2: A kind of brute force approach, which is setting the `encapsulation` property of `@Component` to `ViewEncapsulation.None`. This way, the style will be applied to all the page, without being processed by Angular.

You can check more details about ViewEncapuslation here: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

There is also a [discussion in Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867) about that.

Comment: Apparently ShadowDom is buggy when styling in Safari for slotted option.
And for ViewEncapsulation.None isnt an option for me due to scope bleeding of the css

Comment: There is nothing *brute force* about `ViewEncapsulation.None`. It's the proper *setting* when you need a component's view to be styled in the *global* scope of CSS. It's not a big deal to use it when you need it.

Comment: @cgTag For sure. It is just for emphasizing that it needs to be done cautiously, as you are dealing with global styles. But, as you said, it is a great solution for some cases.