# Angular: Inject CSS from parent to child component

Tags: css, angular

Currently I'm trying to create one [Angular Element](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

To make the Element/Component reusable elsewhere, we need to somehow let parent/host component decide style for the Angular Element i'm working on

I already read [some StackOverflow material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)
which lead me to believe all the ways are deprecated at the moment

I think this is what we can do at the moment

```
<host-element>
      <my-element [getStyle] = "getStyleFnFromHost"> </my-element>
</host-element>
```

I don't feel like this is a good approach, however.

So what do you think I should do at the moment?

**Edit: I would like to clarify that the difference from my question to the question that I refer to is that: I would like to find a good way inject CSS/Style from the parent element to the child element. That does not necessarily involves *cascading* CSS from parent to Child elements**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style child components from parent component's CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Comment: `ViewEncapsulation.None` is the key, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159982/5729813) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the answer you referenced, the `::ng-deep` piercing combinator is still the only way to do what you're asking. Yes, it will very likely be deprecated in the future, but only if and when an appropriate alternative is available (which is not yet the case).

From [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) (highlights by me):

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we *plan* to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep *should be preferred* for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.