# How to set a style of the host component from a transcluded component

Tags: css, angular, transclusion

I have 2 components, a parent and a child. The parent contains the child and uses it to wrap some content and add a title to it.
The child component uses transclusion to achieve that.

The parent template looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <child [title]="componentTitle" class="child">
    <p>some content</p>
  </child>  
</div>
```

The child template looks like:

```
<div class="child">
  <h2 class="title">{{title}}</h2>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

When I try to control the styles using the parent component's CSS, I can deal with all the transcluded content simply enough:

```
.child p {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

However, I'm unable to get to the title element. In other words, the following rule does not work:

```
.child h2.title {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Since parent is the host of child, using `:host` doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style child components from parent component's CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I haven't seen that question, you might be right. I was under the assumption that I couldn't set the style due to the transclusion but I guess the problem is even more basic than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
::ng-deep {
    .child h2.title {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

I think that is deprecated though. The most appropriate way is to pass an input into the child. I recommend:
1) adding a @Input() titleColor to the child class. 
2) .red css style, with background-color: red. to the child css
3) adding a [ngClass]="titleColor" to the child classes h2

Comment: I thought about using inputs, however, I'm trying to set the color using a CSS variable, which I wasn't able to pass.

Comment: One option might be to use scss. That would allow for global variables

Comment: Angular also allows global variables, using the :root pseudo selector, which is what I'm using at the moment. However, the problem is that I don't see a way of passing the name of such a variable to a component and then have that component's CSS evaluate it properly. I've tried passing it as a string as well, which also didn't work