# How is it possible to adjust a component's CSS based on a global CSS class-name in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2viewencapsulation

We are using a class on the `html`-element to determine whether the user is in `dark` or `light` mode of the app.

```
<html class="dark-mode"></html>
```

This class is added using `Renderer2` in a service that detects the selected setting of the user. This works fine so far.

Now, we have to adjust all the components to look good in the dark mode as well. But the problem is Angular's `ViewEncapsulation`.

---

What we thought would come in handy, is to simply update the SCSS of the component:

```
.headline {
    color: black;

    .dark-mode & {
      color: white;
    }
}
```

Or in plain CSS:

```
.headline {
  color: black;
} 

.dark-mode .headline {
  color: white;
}
```

Now this doesn't work, because the class `.dark-mode` seems to be encapsulated, as expected.

---

*How can we solve this problem?*

Comment: You're probably looking for `:host-context` https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context

Comment: @Z.Bagley Wow, now this is excatly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Could you add this as an answer? Might be helpful for other people too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:host-context` provides access to css classes above the `:host`. By using `:host-context` you are able to check if any of the parents of the host have a specific css class and apply styling:

```
:host-context(.dark-mode) h2 {
  color: white;
}
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context