# Angular change child component style from parent component but not globally

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, components, encapsulation

I have created a shared component(`<nextgen-table></nextgen-table>`) based on `Mat-table` (Angular Material). While using this component inside a project, discover that I need to change the behavior(width) of the table columns.

I have exported `nextgen-table` in my other components (let's say X, Y ) where `nextgen-table` is, of course, a child component.

To change the width of specific columns of the mat-table I have to use something like this:

```
mat-cell:nth-child(1),
mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    text-align: left;
} 
mat-cell:nth-child(2),
mat-header-cell:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

The above CSS code I was implementing in the X.component.css and it was not working because of encapsulation I guess.

After a little bit of search, I have found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159982/5875052) which worked correctly just by adding the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the Component decorator of `x.component.ts`. After this solution, I was navigating from the component X to the Component Y in which I didn't implement the above CSS code. But the component Y had the first two columns as I wanted only for component X but somehow component Y had also which I didn't want for the component Y.

So my question is how can I update the style of `nextgen-table` from the parent component which only applies for the parent component and not in the other components.

I have also tried to use

```
:host(mat-cell:nth-child(1)){
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

:host(mat-header-cell:nth-child(1)) {
    flex: 0 0 40%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

but nothing happened/changed.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: you can read this maybe help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528769/9148278](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528769/9148278)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `::ng-deep` [pseudo class](http://%20https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), to specifically target child elements without changing the view encapsultation for the whole component (which would mean that all its rules would leak).

**Note**: `::ng-deep` has been marked as deprecated for since a few major versions now, but they will not remove suppoprt until they have a workaround.

**parentX.html**

```
<div class="compContainer">
    <nextgen-table></nextgen-table>
</div>
```

**parentX.scss**

```
::ng-deep .compContainer nextgen-table
{
    mat-cell:nth-child(1),
    mat-header-cell:nth-child(1) {
        flex: 0 0 40%;
        text-align: left;
    } 
    mat-cell:nth-child(2),
    mat-header-cell:nth-child(2) {
        flex: 0 0 20%;
    }
}
```

You could also add your css rules to the global `style.scss` file.

```
//Rules for parent X
app-parent-componentX .compContainer nextgen-table
{
    mat-cell...
}

//Rules for a parent Y
app-parent-componentY .compContainer nextgen-table
{
    mat-cell...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but this doesn't solve my issue :(

Comment: Can you create an example on  stackblitz showing the problem?

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is use both `:host` and `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selectors in your X or Y component.

Here is the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-deep-demo).

And here is the quick explanation.

styles which are written for the `<nextgen-table>` inside let say `nextgen-table.component.css` are get encapsulated by angular by adding a specific attributes for each style. i.e if you have written something like,

```
.mat-header-cell{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

then it becomes something like,

```
.mat-header-cell[_ngcontent-c29]
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

So all we need to do is to override this style inside our component X or component Y.

We have `::ng-deep` pseudo-selector which will prevent angular from encapsulating out component's css.

But using `::ng-deep` will leak our css on to parent components as well. So to prevent that we need to encapsulate out `::ng-deep` style. to do that we can use `:host` pseudo-selector.

so if we write following css inside component X,

```
:host ::ng-deep .x-table .mat-header-cell{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

then it will become something like,

```
[_nghost-c82] .x-table .mat-header-cell {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

now this above css selection has higher precedence than the style written in the table component `.mat-header-cell[_ngcontent-c29]`.

That's how we can override child component's style inside any parent component.
I hope this will help.

**Update:**
As you can see in [Angular's official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) that  `::ng-deep` is deprecated.

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

So if you don't want to be dependent on `::ng-deep` than,

You can use `ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `<nextgen-table>` table component which you have already tried. [Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-deep-alternative)

And to prevent the style from bleeding into other components you can scope the table's style by adding the selector in front of all the styles like this.

```
nextgen-table .mat-header-cell{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

and then you do the same for your X component.

- Disable view encapsulation using `ViewEncapsulation.None`
- Then override styles on table component by writing styles that have  higher specificity than the table's actual style.

disable encapsulation in side your X component,

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-x",
  styleUrls: ["x.component.css"],
  templateUrl: "x.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class XComponent {

}
```

then override the table's component style in `x.compoent.css`

```
app-x nextgen-table .mat-header-cell{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

If you don't want to disable the view encapsulation then you can write styles directly into global stylesheet  `styles.css`.

Just remember that It's all about overriding and scoping your styles.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution but `ng-deep` is going to be deprecated. what would be an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way i've ever found is to use ::ng-deep

Anything else seems to be "hit or miss" intermittently