# is there a way to change the color of the text depending on the background color of another element in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

In my project, span elements are used to show error messages or control labels. The text color of the messages is red and I need to set the color of the text depending on the background color of the element(f.e. f1 element) which stays behind the span element in UI since I use the error messages on different input elements with different background colors. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

theme.scss file

```
.has-error .help-block, .has-error .control-label {
  color: red;
}
```

login.component.html file

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form, $event)">
  <div upeFormGroup hasFeedback [hasError]="un.invalid">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
             [(ngModel)]="user.username"
             upeFormControl
             name="username"
             #un="ngModel"
             placeholder="User"
             required>
    </div>
    <span [upeHelpBlock]="un.invalid">Please fill the name input</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

auth.component.html file

```
<div fxFlex="grow">
   <div class="form-box">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```

auth.component.scss file

```
.form-box {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` directive to add or remove classes from elements according to a specific state. Read more here https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

**Example**

```
<span [ngClass]="{isError:un.invalid}">Please fill the name input</span>
```

And then in your style file

```
span.isError{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have to reform my question. The span elements with .has-error .help-block class names are used in different components in the project and for each of them, I want to set the text color differently depending on the bg color of different element(in the above example, depending on the .form-box bg color).

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file maybe it could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want change text color depend of the background color who is dynamic:

You could create an angular component:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form, $event)">
  <div upeFormGroup hasFeedback [hasError]="un.invalid">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
             [(ngModel)]="user.username"
             upeFormControl
             name="username"
             #un="ngModel"
             placeholder="User"
             required>
    </div>
    <app-error [ ... ] [isInvert]="isInvert" [message]="message"></app-error>
  </div>
</form>
```

app-error:

```
<span [ngStyle]="{color: '#000', filter: (isInvert ? 'invert(1)' : 'invert(0)')}">
   {{message}}
</span>

// for black and white but use css class for more colors
```