# Angular: styling custom component

Tags: css, angular

I have a component (my-card-component) which is made up of a mat-card with the classes .my-card. I use this component inside two other components. In component "A" I need .my-card to be 380px width, and in component B I need .my-card to be 100% width. The app starts in component A and .my-card is 380px width. Then I navigate to component B and .my-card has 100% width, but if I go back to component A, it doesn't apply the 380px width, instead it keeps the 100% width of component B. I've tried several options, including ::ng-deep .my-card, but I can't get it to apply the width correctly, can someone help me?

my-card-component HTML

```
<mat-card class="my-card">
```

my-card-component CSS

```
.my-card {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: none !important;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.08);
}
```

component A HTML

```
<app-my-card-component></app-my-card-component>
```

component A CSS

```
::ng-deep .my-card {
   width: 380px  !important;
}
```

component B HTML

```
<app-my-card-component></app-my-card-component>
```

component B CSS

```
::ng-deep .my-card {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-afzqwu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Please could you add a StackBlitz to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: No problem, it's ready : )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443318/how-can-i-style-my-child-components-from-parent/68443521#68443521 and your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i6mjxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fa%2Fa.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-card%2Fmy-card.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-card%2Fmy-card.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-card%2Fmy-card.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

place `:host` before `::ng-deep` like `:host ::ng-deep .my-card`

for a

```
:host ::ng-deep .my-card {
  width: 380px;
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

for b

```
:host ::ng-deep .my-card {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-onxbdb?file=src/app/b/b.component.html

The key is to pass in an additional class to the my-card component

component html

```
<app-my-card [extraClassToApply]="'my-card-b'"></app-my-card>
```

my-card.component.ts

```
export class MyCardComponent {

  @Input() extraClassToApply = "";
  constructor() { }
}
```

my-card.component.html

```
<mat-card class="my-card" [ngClass]="extraClassToApply"></mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ::ng-deep since it has been deprecated long time ago.
Instead of ng-deep you should use viewEncapsulaton.None and set for each component a specific class.

[Here is the solution on stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdzir3?file=src/app/b/b.component.css).

With proper css selectors you can make the classes disappear and stop overwriting everything.

with .class1 > * > .class2, you render your rules only if every class is rendered and select class2 no matter what is the cointainer.

Comment: Rememeber that viewEncapsulation.None makes the .css was "global" to all the aplication

Comment: @Eliseo correct. Another way is to implement a css file on the styles source of the project and use proper class selectors to avoid overwriting.