# add styles to child component from parent component angular

Tags: angular, sass

I have a component inside the component I declared **ng-content** so afther that i want to add styles to these components which will be inside the **ng-content**  example bellow

**Parent component**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

now i use the parent component and give some content into the selectors

```
<app-parent-component>
  <div class="block"></div>
</app-parent-component>
```

so in the DOM I have this result
`<app-parent-component>`

`<div class="block"></div>`

`<app-parent-component>`

How can I add class to the block div from parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution look bellow

**parent component html**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**parent component style scss**

```
::ng-deep .block{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**child component html**

```
<app-parent-component>
  <div class="block"></div>
</app-parent-component>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443318/how-can-i-style-my-child-components-from-parent/68443521#68443521

Comment: `:host` is unecessary