# How to set css from another component in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular12

I am trying to change wrapper background color from another component. I ave tried using ::ng-deep But not working properly.
For mauto component background should be like block color.
For vgud component background should be like green color.

mauto.component.css:

```
::ng-deep.wrapper {
  background: red !important;
}
```

vgud.component.css:

```
::ng-deep.wrapper {
  background: green !important;
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-mauto></app-mauto> 
</div>

<div class="wrapper"> 
  <app-vgud></app-vgud>
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
.wrapper{
  width:600px;
  height:240px;
  background: black;
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdhsyh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443318/how-can-i-style-my-child-components-from-parent/68443521#68443521

Answer (score 0):

even considering that it is possible

```
::ng-deep.wrapper:has(app-mauto) {
  background: red !important;
}
```

it is for sure a bad solution.

correct way would be to put styles in the component, whose template contains the elements that you want to style

```
.wrapper {
  ...
  &--mauto { // no ng-deep needed
    background: red !important;
  }
}


------ 
<div class="wrapper wrapper--mauto">
  <app-mauto></app-mauto> 
</div>
....
```

Comment: Your concept is not working. Can you edit in the stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

`app-mauto` and `app-vgud` components shouldn't be responsible for the outside background. I would move the wrappers inside the components and `.wrapper` class to the global styles. Like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzsgah?file=src%2Fstyles.css