# How to change property of html input field that is inside a third party component in angular

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, owl-date-time

I am using the "owl-date-time" component as follows

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
             [owlDateTime]="startDate"
             [(ngModel)]="fromDate">
<div class="input-group-addon" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="startDate" >
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</div>
<owl-date-time #startDate showSecondsTimer="true" (afterPickerOpen)="onOpenStartDate($event)" ></owl-date-time>
```

In the html dom I see this:

[image]

As seen in the image I want to access some **very** inner input element and force the pattern field on the input element to be pattern="[0-9]{2}" or something similar

Can this be done?

Comment: No, unless the author of that library offers an interface for this matter.

Comment: the best way is to be allowed by your library API. So check its doc to see if they allow a pattern to their input. Otherwise, you have to use jQuery, which is not recommended, and will break if the library ever evolves...

Comment: This gives you a very good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528769/15036361. Beware that the best solution would be for the library to support those changes. Also, the solutions provided in the link are now deprecated, with no other alternatives.