# Attaching and toggling a CSS class of element in angular using it's HTML Selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a dropdown component in angular 12. It is shows the selectize like behavior. It is implemented as

```
 <ngx-select-dropdown
        [config]="config"
        [options]="dropdownOptions"
        [(ngModel)]="dataModel"
        [multiple]="false"
      ></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

by using https://github.com/manishjanky/ngx-select-dropdown

After rendering it generates markup like

[image: code generated by the dropdown]

Now, I want to modify the class of the button (highlighted in yellow color) rendered in markup but I don't have direct access to the markup of the button
How can we do that ?

Comment: Have you tried assigning an id to ngx-select-dropdown, then getting the first button? Like: `let button = document.getElementById('yourDropdownId').getElementsByTagName('button')[0]`, then set whatever css styles you want - by directly assigning styles to `button` or adding a specific css class to it. Do that in a code block after the dropdown is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this thread for some older solutions: [How to style child components from parent component's CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file) keep in mind `::ng-deep` is deprecated.

I prefer the following and I will probably add it to that thread.

The only way to get your css to permeate down to a child is to make the css file global. You can use `ViewEncapsulation.None` to make the css of the entire component global, but that's pretty messy. I prefer to just put this global class inside the global `styles.css`, or you can make a new file and add it to the `styles` array in `angular.json`.

So the question is what do we use as the selector? We can't just select `button` as it will override all the buttons in the project, and we don't want to use `.ngx-dropdown-button` alone because we might want different styles for different dropdowns. We want to add a specific class inside the component first. Make sure it is unique, probably best to use the component's name.

```html
 <ngx-select-dropdown
        class="my-component-name-dropdown"
        [config]="config"
        [options]="dropdownOptions"
        [(ngModel)]="dataModel"
        [multiple]="false"
      ></ngx-select-dropdown>
```

Now we can select this specific dropdown from our global styles file. Though, we need to make sure we achieve a high enough specificity to override the default styles. The quick and dirty way is to just use `!important` next to every property, but then you leave no way to override *your* css. A better way is to repeat a class name until we achieve the desired specificity. I found I needed to repeat a class three times here.

**In Global Styles File**

```css
.my-component-name-dropdown
  .ngx-dropdown-button.ngx-dropdown-button.ngx-dropdown-button {
  color: red;
}
```

Or the quick and dirty way

```css
.my-component-name-dropdown .ngx-dropdown-button {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Of course if you want to override all ngx-dropdown-buttons, the unique class is not necessary and you can just use the `.ngx-dropdown-button` class.

**Note:** Many UI components have a `class` option in the config / options object to let you override the default css, you may want to request that the devs add this.