# Angular - Styling Child Component on Parent Component Hover

Tags: css, angular

How do you style a child component when you hover on a parent component, across component boundaries - in Angular 17?

Doing this, in the parent CSS doesn't work on the child:

```
parent:hover .child {
  padding: 0px
}
```

Do I need to use :host ng::deep, even though that is being deprecated? Is there a better way, perhaps, of passing styles from parent to child, when the parent component is being hovered on?

Might there be a way of passing an Input to the child, when hovering on the parent?

Thanks in advance,

ST

**Update - Solution:**

This seems to be the best solution so far, for creating local template variables - though all the LLMs I've used don't recommend using *ngIf in this way (to create local template variables) - but whatever they say, the solution does work!

```
<div *ngIf="{ active: false } as $" (mouseenter)="$.active = true" (mouseleave)="$.active = false"><app-child [active]="$.active" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in parent component ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)).
2. Use `:host-context(.parent:hover) .child` selector in child component ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context)).
3. Use `.parent:hover ::ng-deep .child` selector in parent component. Yes, it's deprecated feature, but it's still widely used.
4. Use additional variable. May be useful for complex scenarios.

   ```
   <div (mouseenter)="active = true" (mouseleave)="active = false">
     <app-child [active]="active" />
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I think the only problem with the mouseenter and mouseleave approach is that I have several childs in the parent, and when one div gets hovered over, all of the childs change. I wanted only the child in the selected div to change.

Comment: @Sachin For each div you can add separate variable or something like `*ngIf="{ active: false } as $"`. But it starts to get messy. I would create separate directive with mouseenter/mouseleave host listeners and use it similar to routerLinkActive: `<div appHover #hover="hover"><app-child [active]="hover.active" /></div>`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using 7 variables, one for each Div. I think a directive is the way to go though, as you suggested.

Comment: 7 additional variables is indeed too many. You can try this if you still don't want CSS or directive: `<div *ngIf="{ active: false } as $" (mouseenter)="$.active = true" (mouseleave)="$.active = false"><app-child [active]="$.active" /></div>`. Each div has its own scope for active.

Comment: Thanks! This worked - even though Bard says, not to use ngIf to create local variables like this. But it does work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HostListener [https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener](https://%20https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

to replicate the hover effect, use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

```
@HostListener('mouseenter') onHover() {
    // trigger child styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the requirement is simple, you can just add the style to `global_styles.css` with a special class for each of the components so that the CSS does not mess up other components. like so.

global_styles.css

```
app-parent-component .parent:hover app-child-component .child {
  padding: 0px
}
```

> here `app-parent-component` and `app-child-component` are the component selectors in angular, this will ensure the CSS gets applied at the proper level!

Comment: you can also include the styles in parent:`.parent:hover app-child-component{...}`

Comment: @Eliseo But it wont reach the child component inner html due to view encapsulation!

Comment: ::glups:: true, only work if you styles directly the "child", but not an html element inside the child. (apologies for confusion)