# When and why should we use View Encapsulation in angular

Tags: css, angular

When working in angular is there a particular rule or guideline that should be used in deciding when to use and why to use [View Encapsulation](http://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None  /*What is the use of this line*/
})
```

Can someone please explain in simple ways?

Comment: Please follow the link for better understand it. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: please add some context / small example. Good question, concerned it will be flagged and removed looking like it currently does.

Comment: Thanks @dince12

Comment: This is the official docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Codecraft.TV**](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/templates-styles-view-encapsulation/) has an amazing article on [**`ViewEncapsulation`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) that you can refer to get a better understanding.

### To just summarize it:

> **`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`**: Angular changes our generic css class selector to one that target just a single component type by using automatically generated attributes.
>
> Any styles we define on a component don’t leak out to the rest of the application but with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` our component still inherits global styles.

---

> **`ViewEncapsulation.Native`**: If we want Angular to use the shadow DOM we can set the encapsulation parameter to use `ViewEncapsulation.Native`
>
> With `ViewEncapsulation.Native` styles we set on a component do not leak outside of the components scope.
>
> This is great if we are defining a 3rd party component which we want people to use in isolation. We can describe the look for our component using css styles without any fear that our styles are going to leak out and affect the rest of the application.
>
> However with `ViewEncapsulation.Native` our component is also isolated from the global styles we’ve defined for our application. So we don’t inherit the global styles and have to define all the required styles on our component decorator.
>
> Finally `ViewEncapsulation.Native` requires a feature called the shadow DOM which is not supported by all browsers.

---

> **`ViewEncapsulation.None`**: If we don’t want to have any encapsulation at all, we can use `ViewEncapsulation.None`.
>
> If we don't encapsulate anything, the style we defined in the component will leak out and started affecting the other components.

Some other resources that you might want to have a look into:

1. [VIEW ENCAPSULATION IN ANGULAR - By Thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)
2. [View Encapsulation by Rangle.IO](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-components/view_encapsulation.html)
3. [Scoping Your Styles in Angular With ViewEncapsulationView](https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/)
4. [Diff between ViewEncapsulation.Native, ViewEncapsulation.None and ViewEncapsulation.Emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651993/diff-between-viewencapsulation-native-viewencapsulation-none-and-viewencapsulat)

Comment: We now also have ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#ShadowDom

Answer (score 1):

Let's take one example where we have one parent and one child component with their own html, ts, css files.

Suppose in parent component's html you referenced child component like below-

```
parent.component.html -> <app-child> </app-child>
```

Now, if you create and add any similar styles like parent.component.css file in child.component.css (let's take `<p>` tag as an example) then those will get added to each component seperately even if all angular component's html gets rendered on single page. 
So now you will have seperate styles for `<p>` in child component.(Behind the scene angular adds one random_atttr to each component and then to all elements inside that component)

This behaviour of angular, comes in view encapsulation. Used by angular like shadow DOM techonlogy which is not supported by all broswers but angular does it like this.
ViewEncapsulation has 3 options -

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
           ViewEncapsulation.Emulated, (-- this is default)
           ViewEncapsulation.Native (-- only applies to browsers with shadow DOM technology)<br>
```