# Apply CSS to <select> and <option> tag in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I want the dropdown list to look something like this.

[image]

I am able to apply the hover effect but I cannot figure out how to move the dropdown list/container downwards and also how to make the edges of the container rounded and give specific border

I want a CSS only solution for this, is that even possible?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS alone since these elements are rendered by the OS itself. You have to recreate these dropdowns via Javascript to get the desired styling.

Comment: @cloned hi, i do not have access to those files(js) rather than the html and css, so isn't there any other way to do that without applying js?

Comment: Devi no, @cloned is right - you have to recreate the dropdown functionality if you want it to be *that* different (with the list separated from the element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was trying to apply `CSS` to `<select>` and `<option>` tag in an Angular project, I used the `mat`(Material) library to implement it.

I found out we can either use the `::ng-deep` selector to overwrite the `mat` tags or we can write  `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the `.ts` file of that respective component

For more detailed info on `::ng-deep` see this post -> [How and where to use ::ng-deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep)

For more detailed info on `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` see this post -> [When and why should we use View Encapsulation in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646933/when-and-why-should-we-use-view-encapsulation-in-angular)